# Is it safe to perform linking and unlinking on a blocked pad from another thread?

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-asyncio

I am working on a highly dynamic gstreamer pipeline, and my code is littered with pad probe callbacks.
It makes it quite unpleasant.
I am using asyncio, so I would like to change this type of code:

```
callback(probe):
    manipulate_pipeline()
    # Now the pipeline has been manipulated...
    return REMOVE_PROBE
pad.add_probe(callback)
```

into this style

```
probe = await pad.add_probe_async()
manipulate_pipeline()
# Now the pipeline has been manipulated...
pad.remove_probe(pad)
```

Is this safe to do? Or am I asking for trouble by returning from the probe callback without removing the probe, and continuing to manipulate the blocked pad from an asyncio thread?

Comment: In lieu of someone more knowledgeable providing an answer here - I have been doing this for some fairly complex dynamic pipelines, and have experienced no issues with it.